# Alternative for sub-query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have query that should return few column results. Also there is one requirement where I have to apply additional filter for one of the columns. I found solution using sub-query (select inside of the main select) here is example:

```
SELECT 
   recid,
   price,
   receive_date,
   (SELECT deduction FROM Cost WHERE recid = c.recid AND status = 'Y') AS deduction
FROM Cost c
   INNER JOIN cost_types ct
      c.recid = ct.recid
WHERE cost_year = '2018'
```

Query above has to pull all records from the `Cost` table that match `cost_type` table records and where `cost_year` is `2018`. On top of that I have to filer `deduction` where `status` is `Y`. I'm wondering what other technique I can use for this query? I know about `UNION / UNION ALL` but that is more code and seems redundant. If anyone have suggestions or better way to approach this situation please let me know. Also, I was wondering if this would be a better fit for Stored Procedure? Would that be recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JOIN` would be the normal method, something like this:

```
SELECT c.recid, c.price, c.receive_date,
       cd.deduction
FROM cost c INNER JOIN
     cost_types ct
     ON c.recid = ct.recid LEFT JOIN
     cost cd
     ON cd.recid = c.recid AND cd.status = 'Y'
WHERE c.cost_year = 2018;
```

This is guessing where the columns are coming from.  Adjust the qualifiers if the columns come from different tables.

You can probably also use a window function:

```
SELECT c.recid, c.price, c.receive_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.status = 'Y' THEN c.deduction END) OVER (PARTITION BY c.recid) as deduction
FROM cost c INNER JOIN
     cost_types ct
     ON c.recid = ct.recid 
WHERE c.cost_year = 2018;
```

Comment: Your first option will eliminate records that I still need in query result. I explained that query should return on top of the current result set additional column that filters where `status` is `Y`.

Comment: @espresso_coffee . . . The first query does not filter out any rows.  You are clearly misunderstanding something about it.

Comment: WHERE clause cost year is filtering records that I'm getting with subquery. In order to get the correct record I need recid from the main query and apply to subquery in combination with status flag. I hope this helps.

Comment: @espresso_coffee . . . No.  Is the query in your question correct?  Your question implies that it is.  The first query should return the same result set -- although some rows might be duplicated (where in your version you would get an error).  The `where` does not filter anything from the `left join` table.

Comment: I see what you are saying. You added `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `subquery`. Is there any reason why your approach is better? Any difference in performance? Thank you!

Comment: @espresso_coffee . . . I have no problem with the subquery -- you asked the question.  Your original query is fine (although it could return an error if multiple rows are returned in the subquery).  The window function is a better approach, but you may not be able to use it, because the `where` filter *does* affect the `deduction` value.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `CASE` ?:

```
SELECT recid, price, receive_date,
      (CASE WHEN status = 'Y' THEN deduction END) AS deduction
FROM Cost c INNER JOIN 
     cost_types ct
     ON c.recid = ct.recid 
WHERE cost_year =  2018;
```

**EDIT :** I suspect you want something :

```
SELECT recid, price, receive_date, c1.deduction 
FROM Cost c INNER JOIN 
     cost_types ct
     ON c.recid = ct.recid OUTER APPLY 
     (SELECT TOP (1) c1.*
      FROM  Cost c1
      WHERE c1.recid = c.recid AND c1.status = 'Y'
      ORDER BY ?? -- Use ordering column based on you want deduction 
     ) c1;
WHERE cost_year =  2018;
```

Comment: I'm getting `NULL` value for the first row `deduction` value. I think that `recid` has to be applied since `INNER JOIN cost_types` returns only 2 records. The `cost_type` has 4 records but `cost_year` is filtering and query returns only 2. I need to look through and get only those where status is `Y` regardless of the `cost_year`. Does that make sense?